# HPLIP Catch-22: Need IP to install printer / need to install to get IP

Tags: wireless, printing, ip

I'm installing an HP Officejet 4155. There are no usb ports on it, and HPLIP can't find it on the wifi without having the IP address first. Of course, to get the IP, I need to access from a computer. What other options are there?

Comment: The add printer in Ubuntu doesn't have the Find Network Printer option?

Answer (score 3):

Print a configuration page by pressing the Wireless button and the Information button on your printer at the same time. It will, among many other items, list its current IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If using a router, log in to the router admin page (usually found from entering the address 192.168.1.1 on a browser page) where you will be able to see the IPs of all connected devices after selecting the appropriate page.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 as a default router address is not an universal rule. Routers use variuos addresses as default. I know one that uses 192.168.100.1 and another that uses 192.168.8.1. Better to check your router's manual, or to check what is the default gateway on your computer (can be checked from connection properties in settings GUI or with `ip route show` command)

Comment: Your experience seems limited. In Germany 192.168.100.1 or 192.168.178.1 are much more common. There is no rule. The most reliable way is to check the default gateway of a device in the network.